# Why is the onPageFinished method not recognized?

Tags: java, android

Basically my search engine logo updates every so often. Trouble is the webpage never updates unless I reinstall the app, so I've disabled the cache.

However it keeps saying:

> Cannot resolve method 'onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView,java.lang.String)'

Here's my code

```
package tk.burningflame.flamesearch;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;  //import WebView class
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;  //import WebViewClient class

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        view.clearCache(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        view.loadUrl("http://www.burningflame.tk/search");
    }

    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After looking [`ActionBarActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html), there's no `onPageFinished` method anywhere in the super class tree. The compiler exception is right.

Comment: @Luiggi is correct, you're thinking about the `onPageFinished()` method of [`WebViewClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html), overriding `onPageFinished` would only be applicable to a class extending `WebViewClient`

Comment: You've asked this same question yesterday, please don't delete posts only to repost them. If you edit your post it will 'bump' it to the recently active queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `onPageFinished()` method in `ActionBarActivity`. You can call `onPageFinished()` method of `WebViewClient` like:

```
    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }

       @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            view.clearCache(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry (No pro here). Only error I get now: Private inner class 'MyBrowser' is never used

Comment: have you used `view.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());` ?

Comment: So sorry man, I figured the issue. Just had a duplicate class for MyBrowser lol. Works now thank you.

Comment: @Onion Happy to help :)